# C# Works with Nest API Restful Auth using HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

Still being new to C#, I am sure that I am not using the HttpClient library properly.  I am trying to authenticate with the Works With Nest API so that I can read/write requests to a thermostat.  Below is the code that I am using to authenticate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;


namespace iConnect.Controllers
{
    public class NestController : Controller
    {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetNestAuthCode()
        {
            // Nest Pin Code
            String pincode = "MYPING";
            String clientID = "My-Client-ID";
            String clientSecret = "MySecretString";
            String grantType = "authorization_code";

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.home.nest.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/oauth2/access_token");

            var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {                
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", pincode)
                , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientID)
                , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret)
                , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", grantType)
            };

            //var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
            //await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            //content.Add(data);
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

            //HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to localhost:9387/Nest/GetAuthCode, I get the following JSON response:

```
{
   "version":{
      "major":1,
      "minor":1,
      "build":-1,
      "revision":-1,
      "majorRevision":-1,
      "minorRevision":-1
   },
   "content":{
      "headers":[
         {
            "key":"Content-Type",
            "value":[
               "application/json"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "statusCode":400,
   "reasonPhrase":"Bad Request",
   "headers":[
      {
         "key":"Connection",
         "value":[
            "keep-alive"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "requestMessage":{
      "version":{
         "major":1,
         "minor":1,
         "build":-1,
         "revision":-1,
         "majorRevision":-1,
         "minorRevision":-1
      },
      "content":{
         "headers":[
            {
               "key":"Content-Type",
               "value":[
                  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
               ]
            },
            {
               "key":"Content-Length",
               "value":[
                  "130"
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      "method":{
         "method":"POST"
      },
      "requestUri":"https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token",
      "headers":[
         {
            "key":"Accept",
            "value":[
               "application/json"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "properties":{

      }
   },
   "isSuccessStatusCode":false
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I've made the following changes and get the following response (which is not what I expect):

Code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetNestAuthCode()
        {
            // Nest Pin Code
            String pincode = "MYPING";
            String clientID = "My-Client-ID";
            String clientSecret = "MySecretString";
            String grantType = "authorization_code";

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.home.nest.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/oauth2/access_token");

            var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {                
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", pincode)
                , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientID)
                , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret)
                , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", grantType)
            };

            //var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
            //await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            //content.Add(data);
            //request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

            //HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("oauth2/access_token",
                    new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Content(content);
        }
```

Response:

```
{"error":"oauth2_error","error_description":"authorization code not found","instance_id":"f64d5268-8bec-4799-927c-e53454ed96d5"}
```

Comment: For the authorization part, have you tried using existing OAuth2 client libraries for .NET (e.g. https://github.com/versionone/OAuth2Client.Net)? It may be easier than getting OAuth2 exactly right by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning you're whole response message back from your action method, with all its properties and values. Instead, you should just read its content and return that. You can find a good article on using the built in .NET `HttpClient` right [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client), if you'd like.

What I would do, is the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNestAuthCode()
{
    // HttpClient setup...

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", "MYPING"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "My-Client-ID"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "MySecretString"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code")
    });

    var response = await client.PostAsync("oauth2/access_token", content);

    // Or check instead with IsSuccessStatusCode
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // ReadAsStringAsync() is just an example here
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Content(responseContent);
}
```

Note that...

- I'm still using an `IActionResult` (or actually `Task<IActionResult>`) as return type. *You shouldn't return the response object.*
- I'm directly using the `PostAsync()` method with the relevant content as `FormUrlEncodedContent`, instead of first building an `HttpRequestMessage` and using `SendAsync()`.
- Also don't forget to check if your request was successful! Otherwise, you might be returning an error message from your action method instead.
- I'm just using `ReadAsStringAsync()` and `return Content()` as an example.

Please note that there is something wrong with your request to the Nest API though, since it returns `400 Bad Request`. You should be able to derive what exactly from the error message in the content. ;)

**EDIT**

I had a very quick look at the Nest API, and I think you're giving the wrong value for `code`. Instead of specifying your PIN code, I think you should first call another API method to retrieve an authorization code before you can exchange it for an access token (as seen [here](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/how-to-auth)).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had to make some modifications to what you sent, for the .NET Core, and now I am getting a new result that isn't what I expect.  I've modified my original question, above.

Comment: @Ronny, you're welcome! I had a quick look at the ASP.NET Core version: for the PostAsJsonAsync() extension method, you need to include the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`. For your result: that's what comes back from the Nest API. Your `HttpClient` instance is actually configured correctly, but you're doing something wrong in your request. I recommend you to check the Nest API documentation for this.

Comment: Why are you advising him to change the request encoding to JSON? It's [clear from the docs](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/rest-quick-guide#post-call) that that's not correct. It should be URL encoded, which is what the OP did.

Comment: @ToddMenier, because of a wrong assumption of mine. I didn't look at the Nest API docs itself, since if felt a bit out of scope of the `HttpClient` question. Thank you for the heads up! I've updated my answer. Also, by looking at the docs, I think you need to call an extra method to retrieve an authorization code.

Comment: @DeveTho , the code variable should contain my pincode.  This is done by going to the unique link that is generated for my project (which is defined by the client_id aand the client_secret), and logging into my Nest account.  Once I do that, and click accept, it gives me a Pincode.  That is where my pincode came from, and it is good for life, or until I deauthorize it.

Comment: @Ronny, I'm sorry when I'd be wrong, but as it is said [here](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/how-to-auth) in step 2, I think you need to retrieve the `code` parameter first. I might be wrong though, I didn't check if very thoroughly. ;)